# Changing property of PictureBox when another PictureBox is selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have 4 PictureBoxes with different background colors. When I click on one, it change's its BorderStyle (so it looks like it's selcted). I want to remove this BorderStyle when I click another PictureBox (so only one PictureBox has this style). This is my first Forms application.

Code for all four PictureBoxes:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
            p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
```

Comment: You'll need a variable to hold the last PictureBox selected.  Or loop through all of them first and change the BorderStyle, then set the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

A micro class that acts as handler for a collection of Controls that share a common behavior.
As it is, it just handles the Controls' border style when one of the items in the collection is clicked, adding an event handler to `Click` event. It can be expanded to perform different tasks.

It implements `IDisposable`, to dispose of the event handlers and the controls added to the collection.

You can add items to the collection using the class Constructor, passing an IEnumerable (List, Array) of controls. It could be modified to add/remove controls when needed.

Add the controls when the class is instantiated; the `Form.Load()` event is a possible choice, but you can of course create it whenever you want.

You can add the controls using their type:
(Add all the PicureBox controls owned by the current Form)

```
PictureBoxHandler pboxHandler = null;

private void Form1_Load(EventArgs e)
{
    pboxHandler = new PictureBoxHandler(this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>());
}
```

Or you can add the controls using each object's reference:

```
pboxHandler = new PictureBoxHandler(new[] { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4 });
```

When you're done with this class, dispose of it, to free the resource it allocated:
(the `Form.FormClosed()` event could be a good *place*)

```
pboxHandler.Dispose();
```

The *manager* class:

```
private class PictureBoxHandler : IDisposable
{
    public PictureBoxHandler(IEnumerable<PictureBox> items) {
        Items = new List<PictureBox>();
        Items.AddRange(items);
        Items.ForEach(i => i.Click += ItemSelected);
    }
    private List<PictureBox> Items { get; }
    private PictureBox Selected { get; set; } = null;

    protected internal void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as PictureBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        if (Selected != null) Selected.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        Selected = (PictureBox)sender;
    }
    public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (Items is null) return;
            Items.ForEach(i => i.Click -= ItemSelected);
            for (int i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Items[i].Dispose();
            }
            Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call all each of your picture boxes directly. All four of your picture boxes (presumably named pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, and pictureBox4) are defined in your form class so they are in scope: ie they can be directly accessed from anywhere in the same class.

Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    pictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    pictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    pictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
    pen.Color = p.BackColor;
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
}
```